# Calculting the angle between two roads on the map

Tags: geometry

Suppose you're given three points $A = (latitude,longitude),B=(latitude,longitude),C=(latitude,longitude)$. There's a road connecting $A$ and $B$ and one connecting $B$ and $C$. How do you calculate the angle between the road $(A,B)$ and the road $(B,C)$ ?

Comment: Presumably, "road" refers to a straight line here, where *straight line* means shortest-length path on the sphere's surface? If roads can be arbitrary paths, I don't think the angle is well-defined...

Comment: @fgp If I can assume the earth is flat, can I calculate the angle as if A,B,C are 3 points on the plane? meaning (m1-m2)/(m1+m2+1) ?

Answer (score 1):

Turn your points into 3D coordinates on the unit sphere, e.g. using [this convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates):

$$
v = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos\varphi\,\cos\lambda \\
\cos\varphi\,\sin\lambda \\
\sin\varphi
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Two points uniquely define a common great circle, which is the intersection of the sphere with a plane through its center. the cross product of the 3D vectors of these points will be a vector which is perpendicular to that plane. Where two great circles intersect, the angle of intersection is the angle between these two planes, which in turn is the angle between the normal vectors. So compute the angle between these two vectors, e.g. via the dot product:

$$\cos\alpha=\frac{(v_A\times v_B)\cdot(v_B\times v_C)}
{\lVert v_A\times v_B\rVert\cdot\lVert v_B\times v_C\rVert}$$